# How to fix image rotation on preview with Exif

Tags: javascript, exif, image-rotation, exif-js

Some of my images are rotating on preview (after user selects them).  I have tried to add an Exif function but it is still rotating pics. I believe I am missing something small.  Am I missing something in my code or maybe a library I need to add?

```
// UPLOAD IMAGE PREVIEW
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = $('#_nc_image_default')
      img.attr('src', e.target.result);
      fixExifOrientation(img)

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

function fixExifOrientation($img) {
  $img.on('load', function() {
    EXIF.getData($img[0], function() {
      console.log('Exif=', EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation"));
      switch (parseInt(EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation"))) {
        case 2:
          $img.addClass('flip');
          break;
        case 3:
          $img.addClass('rotate-180');
          break;
        case 4:
          $img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-180');
          break;
        case 5:
          $img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-270');
          break;
        case 6:
          $img.addClass('rotate-90');
          break;
        case 7:
          $img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-90');
          break;
        case 8:
          $img.addClass('rotate-270');
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: it seems like maybe the image is loading before the exif even gets called.  I tried moving the exif function though but it still doesn't fix the rotation.